# ROR DB association - something missing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I followed "railstutorial.org" example to create "Logs" which belongs to "Tickets". ie. 1 "Ticket" has MANY "Logs". I am able to add "Ticket" at CONSOLE. However, when I try to add  "Log", I got error message "Ticket Can't be blank". (pls see attached picts below) 
I am wondering if you could give me some suggestions/pointers? Thank you in advance. 
Update 2012-09-03: I added the picture of Models. Thank you so much.
[image: img3]
[image: img1]
[image: img2]
[image: model]

update on 2012-09-05: Updated the models to use integer for ticket_id
[image: 20120905]

Comment: I am guessing it has to do with "ticket_id" being defined as a string. It is likely that the ticket model has another integer field id, that is being used for cross-reference purpose when creating Log. Try running `Ticket.first` to see all the fields of a ticket.

Comment: show your models. Do you know that Rails take care of ids? If you let it do the magic you have a Ticket.id wich will be the actual primary key, wish is the one used to create a Log as external key so `Log.create(:ticket_id => some_ticket.id)`

Comment: Can you paste your model code for more clarity.

Comment: 2012-09-04: added model picture, 2010-09-05: changed data type of ticke_id from string to integer.

Comment: Please post code as *text*, not pictures.

Comment: 2012-09-08: was able to find out the root cause. It was because "ticket_id" was not added to "attr_accessible" list in "log.rb". Posted answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the root cause. It was because ":ticket_id" was not added to "attr_accessible" in "log.rb"
The problem was gone after adding ":ticket_id" to "attr_accessible" in "log.rb". (pls see picture below).

Also learnt about "attr_accessible" at link below.
http://madkingsmusings.blogspot.tw/2011/04/attraccessible-and-security-in-rails.html
[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Answer (score 1):

When you execute Ticket.new or Ticket.first, checkout the attributes being displayed. As per the code displayed here, for Ticket model you have created a column ticket_id, rails takes care of the id generation and this attribute can be left considering-

> Convention over configuration

The id generated will serve as primary key and can be used to reference Ticket from Logs.

Comment: Dear GhostRider, thank you for the feedback. I was thinking of using another ticket_id so that I could try to use a customized format, for example, in the form of "yymmdd-001" etc. Thanks :)

Comment: so it's just another attribute in your ticket model.what are trying to display in the last image, the content is a mandatory field and so when you create it with only ticket_id, you get the error which is correct

Answer (score 0):

First Change:

Alter your Migration and make the foreign key as Integer. Using `t.integer :ticket_id` makes the foreign key naming obvious and explicit.

```
t.integer :ticket_id
```

Second:
now try saving the value like

```
obj = Ticket.first
Log.create!(:ticket_id => obj.id)
```

Comment: Dear Ankit, I tried your suggestion: [1] updated the data type [2] use obj = Ticket.first. I still get the similar error. I updated the picture on my post (Pls see the bottom of the post). I believe I need to brush up my foundation. I will try to do something simple. Thank you for your help =)

Comment: @KevinH : How did u update the datatype? Did u change your migration? or altered it? and re run the db:migrate?